# Why did the sleeping gas affect Dynamic Man?

Tags: marvel, comics

Towards the end of Marvel's [The Twelve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_(comics)) series we learn that Dynamic Man

> is actually an Android, not from flesh and blood.

So how is it that the sleeping gas used by the Nazis in the beginning knocked him down as well?

Comment: It could very well have been part of his programming to fall unconscious to keep his façade intact. Whether he was aware of it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### While Dynamic Man is an android of mysterious and unknown design, he does possess vulnerabilities to certain chemical mixtures and a clearly known vulnerability to the element or elemental compound "lantholum."

- Weakness to Lantholum: supposedly a rare earth element, one which modern science has yet to acknowledge, lantholum is an insulative and corrosive material. When exposed to it, Dynamic Man cannot wield his powers.
- While the source of lantholum is unknown, we are also unaware of how many people may know of its existence, either by accident or design. It could have been present in the sleeping gas used to knock out the Twelve.

Comment: Hmm... - wouldn't that be a rather big coincidence? This implies that the Nazis would have prepared the gas specifically targeting Dynamic Man. But the fact that exactly these 12 heroes ended up in the tunnels together was more or less by accident, they didn't operate as a team.

Comment: This is comics. Coincidence is one of the primary cards in play. But it could just as easily been luck that this particular mixture of chemicals affected him. In comics we are often left with such a diverse panoply of characters and superpowers, it is easy to forget sometimes that techniques used to tell stories which work on ordinary characters might not work IN THIS PARTICULAR incidence unless some leeway for coincidence to push the story along. Playing and writing Superhero RPGs taught me just how hard it is to account for every instance of a superheroes vast array of abilities...